# how can i make blender render only the visible parts of the object?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

(i use blender 2.79)
it seems when blender renders an object it does render also the non-visible back of that object and for that reason, it increases the rendering time. 
so to test my theory I had cut an object in half I removed the non-visible part in the back 
and the render time has been decreased.
but doing this to every object i want to make is impractical 
so is there a way to make blender only render the visible parts? inside of rendering everything even the unseens object ?

Comment: Just because parts of objects that are not directly visible to camera doesn't mean they don't contribute to the render solution. They may still be visible in reflections, cast shadows, onto surfaces, bounce light differently, occlude light sources, etc.

Comment: Using cycles, there is a BVH Bounding Volume Hierarchy that is built based on the surface area heuristic and spatial splits that try to optimise what is in the scene, what geometry will go to the GPU etc..
But that won't split back of the objects that may be reflect some of the ray light of the path tracing.